# Salesforce error A workflow or approval field update caused an error when saving this record

Tags: salesforce

I have one object with the name application. I am trying to update all the records of that object at that time it is throwing error message "A workflow or approval field update caused an error when saving this record. Contact your administrator to resolve it.
Division undefined: []" . Why i am getting this error? Application object having some workflow rules with the field update action. I am trying to upadte xyz field with abc field. abc is a formul field it is returning value null. i am updating xyz field with null, i think that reason only i am getting this error. Is this correct or not, if it is correct how to resolve this issue. Please let me know.

Thanks,
Vinod.

Comment: Show us your formula field; in addition give us information about the workflow that your object has.

Comment: In my workflow criteria is 1=1, it means it will work every time when record created ecited. The workflow updating the currency field with the value of formula field(currency type). Formula field returning value 0. Updated value is also blank. I am trying to update all records through console, records are not updating nd showing error message as "System.DmlException:A workflow or approval field update caused an error when saving this record. Contact your administrator to resolve it.
Division undefined: []"

Comment: can you include all of your workflow information in the original question?  Either screenshots or copy/paste - it will greatly help in assisting you!

Answer (score 0):

Given the error returned, and the lack of information provided, my best guess would be that you're dividing by NULL, dividing by 0, or you're referencing a field called `Division` which doesn't exist. In the case of the latter, perhaps you're missing `__c`?

Either way, you'll be unlikely to ever get a particularly useful answer without providing more detail in a scenario such as this.